# java.lang.IllegalStateException occurs only in android production release flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

App crashes when java.lang.IllegalStateException error occurs which is only happens in an Android production release(Android 8.0 and 9 from the google crash report), not in a debug mode. This error only occurs when the app is started at the very first time and error's gone when the app is started right after. I have been searching for the solutions but haven't found one. The app is working perfectly fine on IOS devices. Does anyone have same issue or any ideas to fix this issue? The error messages are as follow

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply (DartMessenger.java:135)
  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error (MethodChannel.java:230)
  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$3.onComplete (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:427)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run (Unknown Source:4)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you configured Firebase properly. Sometimes we need to give Firebase our App certificates hashes for Debug and for Release, maybe you didn't provide those?

Pretend you are configuring Firebase for the first time and recheck every step of the way.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Are you talking about sha-1 keys? I added sha-1 key from App signing(google play console) for the production release and of course i added sha-1 key for the debug. App only crashes at very first launch, then works fine.

Comment: Well, it looks like something is crashing in Firebase Could Firestore, maybe you want to find that method from the library and place a breakpoint while debugging.

Comment: I did some tests and found that the error only occurs in an appbuldle not in an apk. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No, but then I would suggest that you post it as a bug in the Flutter github page. They included app bundle support recently and this could be a bug. Maybe just a bad configuration where the firebase dependencies are not being exported with the bundle.